# How to treat strings in an array as dates

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, date-formatting

I have an array with dates like so:

```
Nov 01 2015 22: +0
Nov 01 2015 23: +0
Nov 02 2015 00: +0
Nov 02 2015 01: +0
```

This is exactly the format I'm getting from the server and I have no control on it. Is it possible to refer all of these as dates? 
For example, I would like to get only those from November 2.

Comment: how about `new Date('Nov 10 2015 22: +0');` ?

Comment: if you want the timestamp, `Date.parse( 'Nov 01 2015 22: +0' );`

Comment: This is working great. I think I'll get along from here, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare each element of your array with a reference date and populate another array with the right dates.

```js
var dates = ['Nov 01 2015 22: +0', 'Nov 01 2015 23: +0', 'Nov 02 2015 00: +0', 'Nov 02 2015 01: +0'];

var referenceDate = Date.parse('Nov 02 2015 00: +0');

var yourDates = [];

function custom(element, index, array) {
    if ( Date.parse(element) >= referenceDate)
    {
     yourDates.push(element);
    }
}

dates.forEach(custom);

console.log(yourDates);

// THIS WILL OUTPUT:
//
// ["Nov 02 2015 00: +0", "Nov 02 2015 01: +0"]
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/w6vz34bb/